# Alter table for a datediff (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, datediff, alter-table, alter

I am trying to alter a table to change one of my column values to `datediff()` but I keep getting an error and I don't see where my issue is.  Here is my code

```
alter table bids
modify column 'timeLeft' datediff(curdate(),'dueDate');
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to change values you should not be using alter table you should be using UPDATE